# How to get string value from Sub procedure in VBA?

Tags: vba

I need to save some string variable to a file in utf-8 encoded.
I've got vba script which can retrive variable from another application.

```
Sub Main
    ChanNum = DDEInitiate("MacroEngine","MacroGetVar")
    Var$ = DDERequest$(ChanNum,"VariableFromOutside")
    DDETerminate ChanNum
    sContent = Var
    MsgBox sContent         
End Sub
```

That script can display sContent only, but i need to processing this string for further in next script as you see below

```
Sub saveUTF_File(FileUrl,sCode)
    ' save text into utf-8 format
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    With objStream
        .Open
        .Charset = "utf-8"
        .Position = objStream.Size
        .WriteText=sCode
        .SaveToFile FileUrl,2
        .Close
    End With
    Set objStream = Nothing
End Sub

FilePath = "C:\file.html"
saveUTF_File FilePath,sContent
```

But it is not wroking because sContent variable is not inherited from Sub Main procedure.
My question is how I can do it? Thanks for advance for any help.

My code now is

```
    Function TextOutside() As Variant

    ChanNum = DDEInitiate("MacroEngine","MacroGetVar")
    Var$ = DDERequest$(ChanNum,"VariableFromOutside")
    DDETerminate ChanNum
    TextOutside = Var
    ' MsgBox TextOutside        

    End Function

    Sub saveUTF_File(FileUrl,sCode)

    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    With objStream
    .Open
    .Charset = "utf-8"
    .Position = objStream.Size
    .WriteText=sCode
    .SaveToFile FileUrl,2
    .Close
    End With
    Set objStream = Nothing
    End Sub

    FilePath = "C:\file.html"
    sContent = TextOutside()
    saveUTF_File FilePath, sContent
```

This script below working without errors but unfortunatly don't want save the result to C:\file.html at all :( why?

```
    Global sContent

    Sub Main()
    ChanNum = DDEInitiate("MacroEngine","MacroGetVar")
    Var$ = DDERequest$(ChanNum,"VariableFromOutside")
    DDETerminate ChanNum
    sContent = Var
    MsgBox sContent         
    End Sub

    Sub saveUTF_File(FileUrl,sCode)
    ' save text into utf-8 format
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    With objStream
    .Open
    .Charset = "utf-8"
    .Position = objStream.Size
    .WriteText = sCode
    .SaveToFile FileUrl,2
    .Close
    End With
    Set objStream = Nothing
    End Sub

    Sub DoAll()
    Dim FilePath 
    '
    ' Main is called before here.
    '
    FilePath = "C:\file.html"
    saveUTF_File FilePath, sContent
    End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you calling `saveUTF_File` from, how does it get its parameter values? Are the lines below `End Sub` actually somewhere else?

Comment: saveUTF_File got FilePath it is paht to save my utf-8 file and sContent variable which should came from Sub Main procedure where is VariableFromOutside also. I need only that two script working together nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you, This may be a solution, I would also propose you to declare explicitly all variables wiht Dim keyword, let's use dirty global variable solution:

```
Global sContent

Sub Main()
  ChanNum = DDEInitiate("MacroEngine","MacroGetVar")
  Var$ = DDERequest$(ChanNum,"VariableFromOutside")
  DDETerminate ChanNum
  sContent = Var
  MsgBox sContent         
End Sub

Sub saveUTF_File(FileUrl,sCode)
  ' save text into utf-8 format
  Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  With objStream
    .Open
    .Charset = "utf-8"
    .Position = objStream.Size
    .WriteText=sCode
    .SaveToFile FileUrl,2
    .Close
  End With
  Set objStream = Nothing
End Sub

Sub DoAll()
  Dim FilePath 
'
' Main is called before here.
'
  FilePath = "C:\file.html"
  saveUTF_File FilePath, sContent
End Sub
```

You call DoAll() by a command button after calling Main.

Comment: Might be less confusing if the signature for `Main()` was `Function Main() As String`... but `Main` is an awfully bad name for a function...

Comment: @retailcoder, yes Main() is a bad function name. But VBA may tolerate it. Ignoring variable type has an advantage to use this kind of script in VBScript without modifications, executable directly in Windows Shell.

Comment: VBA doesn't care what the function name is :) it's just implicitly making it `Function Main() As Variant` if you don't specify a return type. Also kudos for explicit declaration, I'd even recommend to systematically use `Option Explicit`.

Comment: @retailcoder, yes, all is implicitly of Type Variant in this code.

Comment: Where the error comes from ? Can you post your Error message and the whole new code to let us take a look?

Comment: Please comment the line MsgBox TextOutside, it may cause recursive execution.

Comment: It seems that DDERequest$ don't want working in function structure but within sub Main procedure only.

Comment: *RunThis1*#26: <here>FilePath = "C:\file.html" (0) Unexpected text. That strange message I'm getting each time.

Comment: @jacouh, what do you mean I have to call DoAll() by a command button ? I have no possibilities to make any command button.

Comment: On an Access Form, add a button, give event OnClick="DoAll()", you can do similar thing on an Excel UserForm; Or call it by a Macro, or in VBA code mode, click on a line of DoAll Sub, Press F5 to run it...

Comment: In your mother application (Access, Excel, Word, PP) of VBA, press Alt-F11 key for Code. then Ctrl-G, you'll have a run prompt window. Type DoAll, it will be run.

Comment: @jacouh, but I want the script sould working automatically without my participation, please.

Comment: VBA is embedded in Office Application. What's it? Access, Excel, Word... in all of them, you can add a button to run a sub, also called macro.

Comment: @jacouh, you do not understand the script is part of the large macro that was launched earlier. Everything have to go completely automatically. By the way I'm working with Macro ToolsWorks program. The program uses the script leaves it and forget about him. If there is no another solution for that, anyway thanks very much for help.

Comment: You would have some place in the program flow the possibility to insert your code.